# Health & Distance Variables Not Reducing

Tags: unity-game-engine, logic, unityscript

The mechanics are set up so that when the user input ("Fire1") the distance is updated and health is deducted if the distance that the raycast found is less than or equal to 1.5.

However when I click the mouse button the distance variable is not updated thus nor is the health.

**

> Melee System Code

**

#pragma strict

```
var Damage : int = 50;
var Distance : float;
var MaxDistance : float = 1.5;

function update ()
{

if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
{
var hit : RaycastHit;
if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), hit))
{
Distance = hit.distance;

if(Distance < MaxDistance)
{
 hit.transform.SendMessage("Apply Damage", Damage, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
}




}
}
}
```

> Enemy Logic Code

```
#pragma strict

var Health : int = 100;

function ApplyDamage(Damage : int)
{

Health -= Damage;



}
```

*
**Please Explain All Changes.**
*

Comment: Try replacing `"Apply Damage"` with `"ApplyDamage"`

Comment: The change @ManofSnow suggested is correct, since the way it is now it can't call the `ApplyDamage` function. Beyond that however, try sticking a couple of `Debug.LogWarning(...)` in your update function. Which ones are triggering? Is the `if (Physics.Raycast...` ever true (ie hitting something)? Are you sure Vector3.forward is the correct direction?

Answer (score 3):

Other than the solution suggested by Man of Snow (certainly correct), another error is the lower-cased "u" in the `update()` function. The real function that you wanna call is `Update()` (with the upper-cased "U"). "`update()`" is a function that's actually never called, not the one invoked each frame by Unity.